# What would make a good "Session 0" in Pathfinder with both new and experienced players?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, group-dynamics

Many questions from [problem-x](/questions/tagged/problem-x) tags get answers stating something like "have a Session 0", which means "sit down and tell each other what do you expect from the game". Some of them mention the [Same Page Tool](https://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/). But what *exactly* should I do during that "Session 0"? What should be my plan? What should I *not* do?

I need advice applying to *Pathfinder* games in groups of mixed experienced levels, from "I have read the PHB yesterday" to "I have tried D&D the same year it was released", because while the latter know their desires, the former likely don't.

As I can get it from the questions here, lots of the problems may arise, and I would like to shut them down in advance.

Comment: See https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/can-a-question-about-what-makes-a-good-session-0-be-made-on-topic.  A "good" Session 0 is in the eye of the beholder, you don't provide enough specific goals for us to say.  "New and experienced" explains the context a little, but not the goals, and "head off problems" is super broad.

Comment: I have some thoughts on this. Maybe we could chatroom about it?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63362/session-0